# Xcode 5 Simulator bug - doesn't show NSMutableAttributedString text

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, ios-simulator, nsattributedstring

I've created an app with the preview version of Xcode 5 that loads items from a Core Data file and shows the title of the items in a UITableView. The app worked fine on the simulator and my device! Here is a snippet from the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:item.title];

[attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                        value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
                        range:(NSRange){0,[attributeString length]}];

cell.titleLabel.attributedText = attributeString;
```

Now I use the official Xcode 5 version from the App Store and my UITableView doesn't show the texts of the items in the cells (on simulator). But the items are loaded and I didn't change any code! - Beside the app works on my device...

So I changed the attributed text of the cell label to plain text:

```
cell.titleLabel.text = item.title;
```

Now it works and the title of the items is shown in the table view/cell text label.

Why doesn't it work with an NSMutableAttributedString is this a simulator bug?

Comment: does it works on device?

Comment: Well is it `item.title` or `activity.title`?  Did you check that `item.title` is not nil or empty?

Comment: yes it works on device. oh sorry: item.title of course. no it is not nil. thats very strange. i can even print out the title with nslog. i guess the simulator can't handle attributedstrings. the preview xcode simulator and my device are running the app fine.

Comment: I got this problem too, but only if UILabel text is single-line. If it multi-line, label draws good.